# Azure Subscription Event failed to create resource group 'undefined'

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Trying to deploy an Event Grid instance to harvest ARM events on my subscriptions. This instance is deployed on the subscription blade:

[image]

However, I get this error message when trying to deploy the event grid instance on the subscription.

[image]

I guess this is the resource group that has to be created in the background as the Event Grid instance cannot reside in a resource group to access events at the subscription level.

Cannot find any documentation on this error. Please advise.

Comment: Which way do you create the Event Grid instance?

Comment: The Event Grid instance is created in the background when setting up Events via the subscription blade as seen in the screenshot in the original post.

Comment: So the your issue is whwat the error shows. You need to check if the resource group exists.